# Yarn always ends in error when i use create command

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm getting this same error every time I try to run the create command with yarn, example with create-react-app:

```
PS M:\Users\Michael\Documents\GitHub\test> yarn create react-app test-app --template typescript
yarn create v1.22.11
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "create-react-app@4.0.3" with binaries:
      - create-react-app
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: M:\Users\Michael\Documents\GitHub\test\!\bin\create-react-app
Arguments: test-app --template typescript
Directory: M:\Users\Michael\Documents\GitHub\test
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

Maybe I need some environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is from windows.

I got it fixed by installing `create-react-app` globally and use it to create app instead of npx.